# Proof regarding sum of 2 squares

Tags: number-theory

I am sorry for posting a picture first and foremost but I am in a time crunch. I have tried to think about why myself a lot, but I just can't figure it out.
[image: Proof from my notes]

If you read from "Assume that $n=x^2+y^2$." I have a problem finding out why the conclusion is that p can only occur an odd amount of times. Is it because we assumed $p$ and not for example $p^2$?

Comment: They showed that after dividing $n$ by $d^2$ all the prime factors left were equal to 1 mod 4. Thus any prime factors equal to 3 mod 4 had to divide $d^2$ meaning they had to occur an even number of times in the factorization of $n$.

Comment: @irh Thank you, that makes sense.